# Two problems with symfony forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I've created simple form which allows users to enter comments. But what i want to achieve is the comment to be saved to the database for particular user ( lets say for the user id ) I have not idea how to do that. Here is what i ve done :

```
function some Controller(){
    $baza = new baza();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($baza);

    $comment = $this->createFormBuilder($baza)
                ->add('comment', 'text')
                ->getForm();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $comment->bind($request);
        if ($comment->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();
            echo "your comment have been submited";
        }

    return $this->render('AcmeWebBundle:Default:index.html.twig'
        ,array('users'   => $users
              ,'count'   => $total
              ,'comment' => $comment->createView()
    ));
}
```

But in this way the comment is not saved for particular user, instead new row in the database is created :/

And in addition is twig code:

```
  {% extends 'AcmeWebBundle:Default:master.html.twig' %}
{% block strana %}
<h3>Total users: {{ count }} </h3>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<h1> Recently booked</h1><br></br>
{% for user in users %}
<strong><em>{{ user.username}}</em></strong><p> From : <b>{{ user.from }}</b> To : <b>{{ user.to }}</b><br></br>
Car: <b>{{ user.car}}</b> &nbsp;Leaving on : <b>{{ user.date }}</b><br><br>
Price: <b>{{ user.price }} </b><br></br>
Comments:<br></br> {{ user.comment }} //* first to display all the comments, and than add another one *//
<br><br>

    <form action="{{ path('acme_web_homepage') }}"  method="post" {{ form_enctype(comment) }}>
        {{ form_widget(comment) }}{{ form_widget(comment['comment']) }}
     {{ form_rest(comment) }}

        <input type="submit" value=" New Comment" />
    </form>

    <br><br>-------------------------------
    </p>
    {% endfor %}{% endblock %}
```

Also empty field for comment body is displayed only once, for the first user... Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to item 1:

```
form->bind($request);
```

puts the data from the form into the entity; therefore you need to persist *after* bind.  Try:

```
    $baza = new baza();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($baza);

    $comment = $this->createFormBuilder($baza)
                    ->add('comment', 'text')
                    ->getForm();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $comment->bind($request);

    if ($comment->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($baza);        // Lighthart's change
        $em->flush();
        echo "your comment have been submited";
    }
```

Also, it is not obvious why you would persist an empty object, but it is not explicitly a bad idea to do so.

The second item cannot be addressed without seeing controller code, and I recommend you submit a new question so crosstalk does not dilute the answer.

Comment: Thank you indeed Lighthart .

Comment: Did you post the second half of your question to another place yet?

Comment: i decided to use facebook for adding comments. Thank you anyway .